# Remove border around DataGridViewButtonColumn

Tags: vb.net

I found a solution here on how to set an image for a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. I set the `FlatStyle` of the column to `Flat` and now I want to get rid of the boarder around the button (the Delete button) but there does not seem to be a `BorderSize` property for `DataGridViewButtonColumn` which I would have set to 0.

[image]

To draw the button image, I use

```
If dgvPaymentList.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "xDelete" AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.delete16White, CInt((e.CellBounds.Width / 2) - (My.Resources.delete16White.Width / 2)) + e.CellBounds.X, CInt((e.CellBounds.Height / 2) - (My.Resources.delete16White.Height / 2)) + e.CellBounds.Y)
        e.Handled = True
End If
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataGridViewButtonCell` with the `FlatStyle` property set to `FlatStyle.Flat` uses the cell's `ForeColor` and `SelectionForeColor` to draw the border part. You can find that in the source code, [how the border color is selected](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewButtonCell.cs,720) and [passed](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewButtonCell.cs,805) to the draw border method. Hence, the easiest workaround to get rid of the border is to assign the cell's `BackColor` to the `ForeColor` and `SelectionForeColor` properties.

Use the designer to apply that or through the code:

```vb
Public Class YourForm

    Private ReadOnly img As Bitmap

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        img = My.Resources.delete16White

        Dim c = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)

        ' Your button column...
        xDelete.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = c
        xDelete.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = c
        xDelete.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = c
        xDelete.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = c
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClosed(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnClosed(e)
        img.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvPaymentList_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgvPaymentList.CellPainting
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = dgvcButton.Index Then
            Dim r = e.CellBounds
            Dim imgRec = New Rectangle(
                r.X + (r.Width - img.Width) \ 2,
                r.Y + (r.Height - img.Height) \ 2,
                img.Width, img.Height)

            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, imgRec)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Alternatively, takeover and draw the whole thing yourself the way you like:

```vb
Private Sub dgvPaymentList_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgvPaymentList.CellPainting
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = xDelete.Index Then
        Dim r = e.CellBounds
        Dim imgRec = New Rectangle(
            r.X + (r.Width - img.Width) \ 2,
            r.Y + (r.Height - img.Height) \ 2,
            img.Width, img.Height)

        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, False)

        If e.CellBounds.Contains(dgvPaymentList.PointToClient(MousePosition)) Then
            Dim backColor As Color

            If MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Left Then
                backColor = Color.FromArgb(104, 104, 104)
            Else
                backColor = Color.FromArgb(84, 84, 84)
            End If

            Using br As New SolidBrush(backColor)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, r)
            End Using
        End If

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, imgRec)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The second option worked brilliantly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code it's a little hard to help you...
Try removing the following line:

```
e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
```

In fact, if the column was obtained with a code similar to this

```
Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn() With {
    .HeaderText = "Example",
    .Text = "Click Me",
    .UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True,
    .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat 'Or others
}
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn)
```

the `e.Paint` line will draw the button (border + fillcolor + text). Without it, however, the button design will not be rendered.

You may need to draw a rectangle behind the image for the background color.